# Mesh Deform Modifier Missing / not visible

Tags: modifiers, interface

When I use a modifier, they work fine, but when I use the *Mesh Deform Modifier* it is not visible for some reason. When I move any other modifier, it becomes visible; if I let go of it, it turns back to being invisible.

Also the modifier underneath it become only togglable. Any other button I select ( The Drop Down menu with the options to move first or last, apply Modifier, etc...) aren't selectable.

I am also unable to duplicate the modifier

I have reinstalled Blender.
and it has changed nothing.

Edit:

After a few hours away, I came back to find it still the same.
However I did encounter the steps to generate the problem;

Make two Mesh Deform Modifiers and apply both to a mesh.
I first have an armature modifier, a corrective smooth modifier, subsurf, and then the two Mesh Deforms last.

I tried to rearrange the stack of the mods since I remember reading somewhere that the order in which the Modifiers are stacked yields undesirable results, and wouldn't I know it, just by rearranging the stacks the second mesh deform disappeared from the UI, so adjusting the stack generates this issue.

However, rearranging them, does not solve this one for me.

I will get a photo uploaded soon to show what I mean.

[image: You can see the extra space between the two modifiers.]

[image: Below the Modifier is visible, however, only when I select the upper right corner to move/rearrange the modifier within the Stack.]

The first photo on top you can see the extra space between the modifiers

In the first image above you can see the modifiers are visible, but only when I select the upper right corner to move/ rearrange the modifiers within the Stack.

Comment: Hello, this looks awfully like a bug someone encountered a few days ago here. Unfortunately this is not the right site for troubleshooting bugs in Blender. You should go to https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports or directly inside blender go to Help > Report a bug : that will generate a pre-filled form for you.

Comment: Also screenshots are prefered to photographies of your screen : https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/

Comment: I will do that Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

DISCLAIMER: THIS IS NOT AN ANSWER! I am only taking this matter elsewhere since this may be a legit bug worth reporting. I think I will keep this up in case anyone else has anything to contribute; but for the time being, I will be taking this issue up with Blender Stack exchange.